# Postcode to City search

Tags: here-api

we are trying to find cities to postcodes, but we are running into the issue, that in case there is multiple cities to the same postcode, we cannot get here-api to return a list of cities where that postcode matches

we tried:
http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_id=...&app_code=...&country=DEU&language=de&resultType=postCode&query=56237
with various combinations

we tried:
https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=...&app_code=...&country=DEU&language=de&searchtext=56237
with various combinations

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should specify the question, it's too generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try by putting app_id and app_code, this resulting in all the cities corresponding to the postalCode.

```
http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxxx&country=DEU&language=de&resultType=postalCode&query=56237
```